# Ken Burns plugin 100% width

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

Ok, I'm trying to modify a Ken Burns jQuery plugin that I got off Code Canyon. The client wants it to be 100% width all the time.

But because the plugin is responsive, it's always adjusting it whenever I resize the browser. No matter what I do, there's always a sliver of the background showing on the right. If anybody enjoys looking through 23 element layers per slide to figure out what I need to adjust to get it to 100% width, I'd be very grateful.

The link is http://www.yaregroup.com/bpg-werks

Comment: "100%" is by its very nature, responsive. Do you mean to say your client wants the slide to maintain a fixed width in pixels, regardless of browser/screen size, instead?

Comment: ask the author for support....

Answer (score 0):

have a look at these divs/classes:  canvas-now 
& the < canvas > with class - canvas-now-canvas

They are probably in the js files giving height & width based on the window size, on the fly.  This div/canvas does not extend far enough to the right, leaving background on the right.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is super old, but in case anyone else comes across this, I've got a free plugin here that does what you need: http://kthornbloom.com/smoothslides.php